# Can you use LEN in SelectLayerByAttribute_managment in Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I am trying to use LEN to select all strings in a Column that are a length of a phone number, and am unable to enter the correct expression, is it possible to use LEN in SelectLayerByAttribute_management ?

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Contacts_tbl", "NEW_SELECTION", "LEN(Contact_Phone_Work) = 12")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for [`CHAR_LENGTH`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm#ESRI_SECTION2_FA1A575451D64E20809DF39DE686DDEB)

> CHAR_LENGTH(string_exp)
>
> Returns the length in characters of the string expression.

```py
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Contacts_tbl",
                                        "NEW_SELECTION",
                                        "CHAR_LENGTH(Contact_Phone_Work) = 12")
```